# Python - How to remove a deep nested node in dict by path?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
// obj.json
{
  "first": [
    {
      "second": {
         "third": "value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After I load json into dict, is there a way to delete `"value"` like:

```
path_to_delete = ['first.[0].second.third']
for p in path_to_delete:
    deleteByPath(obj, p)
```

Comment: `obj["first"][0]["second"].pop("third")` should work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is not what I want. As callee, I hope to provide a single string so that all the stuff can be done. Imagine I have a list of paths.

Comment: Can you settle for providing a list `['first', 0, 'second', 'third']`? That would make things much easier.

Comment: @AlexHall and that would be a duplicate. As opposed as currently: this is too broad. the idea is to parse the string, and access the keys to get sub-elements iteratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a functional solution. Identifying integer list indices versus string keys is the messy part, but is dealt with here via a list comprehension.

```
d = {"first": [{"second": {"third": "value"}}]}

from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def removeFromDict(dataDict, mapStr):
    mapList = [int(i[1:-1]) if i.startswith('[') and i.endswith(']') \
               else i for i in mapStr.split('.')]
    del reduce(getitem, mapList[:-1], dataDict)[mapList[-1]]
    return dataDict

d = removeFromDict(d, 'first.[0].second.third')

print(d)

{'first': [{'second': {}}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I want. BTW, I will polish it to catch some exception cases. :)